# Three Tiered Arrays in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, swift3

I am only just learning Swift, so excuse me if this is a simple question. But I am really struggling to have an array that is three levels deep, and to show the third level of data.

I have tried searching on this already, but all multi-dimensional array questions seem to just be aimed at 2 levels. Maybe I need to approach this a different way?

```
let cars = [
    ["volvo", ["red", "petrol", "automatic"], ["blue", "petrol", "manual"], ["white", "diesel", "automatic"]],
    ["bmw", ["green", "petrol", "manual"], ["white", "petrol", "manual"], ["white", "diesel", "automatic"]],
    ["ford", ["black", "diesel", "automatic"], ["grey", "diesel", "manual"], ["blue", "petrol", "automatic"]]
]
let catData = cars[0][3]
```

Returns fine... but if I try this:

```
let cars = [
    ["volvo", ["red", "petrol", "automatic"], ["blue", "petrol", "manual"], ["white", "diesel", "automatic"]],
    ["bmw", ["green", "petrol", "manual"], ["white", "petrol", "manual"], ["white", "diesel", "automatic"]],
    ["ford", ["black", "diesel", "automatic"], ["grey", "diesel", "manual"], ["blue", "petrol", "automatic"]]
]
let catData = cars[0][3][1]
```

I get this error: Value of type 'Any' has no subscripts

All I want to do is nab the individual colour or transmission of a car by using a three level array, but I am not sure if that will actually work... help!

Comment: Here is a quickfix : `let catData = (cars[0][3] as! [String])[1]`. (optional binding is advised)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your array is not a 3D array:

```
["volvo", ["red", "petrol", "automatic"], ["blue", "petrol", "manual"], ["white", "diesel", "automatic"]]

 ^ this is a simple String                         ^ this is an array
```

Therefore your second dimension is composed from `String` and from `[String]`.

A real 3D array would be `[[[String]]]`, however, since your second tier is composed from different types, it becomes `Any` and the whole type becomes `[[Any]]`.

Solution, declare a `struct`:

```
struct CarModel {
   let color: String
   let fuel: String // could be replaced by an enum
   let gear: String // could be replaced by an enum
}

let cars: [String: [CarModel]] = [
    "volvo": [
       CarModel(color: "red", fuel: "petrol", gear: "automatic"),
       CarModel(color: "blue", fuel: "petrol", gear: "manual"),
       CarModel(color: "white", fuel: "diesel", gear: "automatic")
     ]
]

print(cars["volvo"]![2].fuel)
```

Comment: Thank you, that is awesome. I will look at that. As an extra, I have realised now that part of what I want to do is show the colour visually, as a square next to the name - so I need to be able to do something like this:

```myCar.backgroundColor = UIColor.red```

But swap out red for whatever is in the variable, but it just pings back with an error... so how can I pass that red value into a UIColor command?